# Need help stopping at parenthesis

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm new with regex and really need some help here. I'm trying to create a regex that finds everything before the first space and open parenthesis in the example below. Basically, I'm trying to just keep the country name or names and exclude everything after.

**Falkland Islands** (Malvinas)

I tried this but it isn't working:

```
(\w+)(?=[\s+(\w+\s+])
```

Comment: `\w+(?:\s+\w+)*(?=\s*\()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
^.*?(?=\s*\()
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ps8TsS/1) here.

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```